# Dirty worktree with a twist: that worktree isn't in my workspace

Tags: eclipse, git, gitblit

I'm having an issue in Eclipse in that my pull attempt fails, returning dirty worktree and naming a particular file. That's all fine and good--dealt with that in the past, but the issue this time is that the file is in a tree that I don't have in my local repo. How can I clean up the tree and complete the pull?

Comment: Ultimately I couldn't figure out what the issue was, as doing git reset didn't work. Tried adding the missing worktree to no avail. Wound up nuking it, rebranching, and cutting my losses.

Comment: Ok, I have added a similar conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Alright, to add to this, I encountered the exact same problem shortly after my "fix." Luckily this time I had the offending worktree present in my workspace. Deleting the offending file actually solved the issue and it was replaced in the pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have no work in progress, you can try the nuclear option of:

```
cd /path/to/your/local/repo
git reset --hard
```

That should reset your working tree to a clean state.

---

If that isn't working, re-cloning the all repo in another path, and re-importing it into Eclipse can help, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794184/dirty-worktree-with-a-twist-that-worktree-isnt-in-my-workspace/24795883#comment38510008_24794184) by the [OP octopushugs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2966334/octopushugs).

> I encountered the exact same problem shortly after my "fix." Luckily this time I had the offending worktree present in my workspace.
>   Deleting the offending file actually solved the issue and it was replaced in the pull.

Comment: Tried using eclipse to do a git reset both hard and soft, then tried it on the command line, but no dice.